# Adding contents to a variadic template type after instantiation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, stdvector

**Current Source**

At this point in my code I have this variadic template class:

```
template<typename ClassType, std::size_t... Args>
class Matrix {
private:
    DimensionPack<Args...> dp;

public:
    Matrix<ClassType, Args...>(){} // Default

    // Public Access Members To Get Information From the DimensionPack which is based
    // Not On The Type But Based On The Amount & Values Of This Template's Variadic Parameters
    std::vector<unsigned int>& getDimensions() { return dp.dimensions;  }
    std::vector<unsigned int>& getEvenOrOdd() { return dp.even_or_odd; }
    const unsigned int getNumberOfDimensions() const { return dp.total_dimensions; }
    const unsigned int getTotalNumElements() const { return dp.total_elements; }

};
```

It uses this class and structure to do the needed calculations based on its variadic parameter list of values passed in `(std::size_t...)`.

```
const unsigned int EVEN = 0;
const unsigned int ODD  = 1;

struct MatrixDimensionOddOrEven {
    const unsigned int even_or_odd; 
    explicit MatrixDimensionOddOrEven( unsigned int odd_or_even ) : even_or_odd( test( odd_or_even ) ) {}

private:
    const unsigned int test( unsigned int value ) const {
        if ( value == 0 ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << "invalid number: " << value << " must be >= 1.";
            Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        }
        return ( ((value % 2) == 0) ? EVEN : ODD );
    }
}; typedef MatrixDimensionOddOrEven MatDimOddEven;

template <std::size_t... Dims>
class DimensionPack {
public:
    std::vector<std::size_t> dimensions;
    std::vector<unsigned int> even_or_odd;
    const std::size_t total_dimensions = sizeof...(Dims);
    const std::size_t total_elements = countElements();

public:
    DimensionPack() : dimensions{Dims...},
        even_or_odd{ MatrixDimensionOddOrEven{Dims}.even_or_odd...} {
    }

private:
    std::size_t countElements() {
        std::size_t val = 1; // Don't Init to 0 otherwise multiplication won't work here!
        for ( std::size_t n = 0; n < dimensions.size(); n++ ) {
            val *= dimensions.at( n );
        }
        return val;
    }
};
```

At this point in my `Matrix` class I am able to successfully compile and get the results that are expected such as in these cases:

Examples Of Use:

```
Matrix<float, 1> mat1;   // Single Element Matrix - Considered A Scalar Type
Matrix<float, 1,1...> mat1...; // Again - Single Element Matrix - Considered  A Scalar Type
Matrix<float, n, m, 1, p> matNM1P; // Where n,m,p are > 1 makes that field of dimensionality flat such as a linear array or vector.
Matrix<float, 2,2> mat2x2; // creates a 2x2 Matrix with 4 elements of type float
Matrix<int, 3,3,3> mat3x3x3; // creates a 3x3x3 Volumetric Matrix with 27 elements of type int.
Matrix<type,n...> mat_multidimensional; // creates any higher order dimension of type.
```

I can pass them to this function to get the correct results and values:

```
template<typename type, std::size_t... dims>
void testMatrix( Matrix<type, dims...> matrix ) {
    std::cout << "The Matrix Has " << matrix.getNumberOfDimensions() << " Total Dimensions:\n";
    std::cout << "The Dimensions Are:\n";
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < matrix.getDimensions().size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << matrix.getDimensions()[u] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The even and odd of each dimension are:\n";
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < matrix.getEvenOrOdd().size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << matrix.getEvenOrOdd()[u] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The Matrix Has " << matrix.getTotalNumElements() << " total elements.\n\n";
}
```

Making my main.cpp look like this:

```
#include <Matrix.h>

int main() {
    Matrix<float, 2, 3, 4> mat;
    testMatrix( mat );

    Matrix<int, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17> mat2;
    testMatrix( mat2 );

    Matrix<double, 255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255> mat9;
    testMatrix( mat9 );

    return 0;
}
```

Everything up to this point works fine and the results are expected.

---

**The Goal**

As you can see my `Matrix` class has a default constructor and now it is time to add contents to it. And this is where I'm sort of stuck.

*For Example:* If a user did the following they would have:

```
Matrix<float, 4,4,4> mat4x4x4;  // A 3D Volumetric Matrix With 256 Elements
Matrix<float, 2,3,5> mat2x3x5;  // A 3D Volumetric Matrix With 30 Elements
Matrix<float, 5,7,8,10> mat5x7x8x10; // A 4D Volumetric Matrix With 2800 Elements
```

- Should I just accept a single `vector<type>` that has a fixed size that 
  matches the total amount of elements and create an indexing scheme?
- Should I have nested `<vector<vector<type>>` where the amount of nested vectors matches the number of dimensions if the automation of doing such a thing can be done?
- Should I create a helper structure that will nest up to 3 nested vectors then repeat that process if the automation of it can be done?

This is where I'm looking for good sound advice as to what my options should be and how it can easily be done.

Comment: If you know sizes at compile time instead of `std::vector`s use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)s

Comment: @W.F. The size are coming from the template's variadic list that happens to be `std::size_t...` The template instantiation shows the sizes such as `Matrix<type, M,N>` would give you MxN elements within 2 dimensions and `Matrix<type, M,N,O>` would give you MxNxO elements within 3 dimensions. And there is no set amount of dimensions so in theory it can be a 100 dimensional matrix, not that the hardware would support it due to restrictions of data types and the values they can contain.

Comment: So there you go - you know sizes at compile time. In this case using arrays will be more appropriate...

Comment: @W.F. ty for the advise, I'll have to try it.